# Android Studio - How to find EditText in tab1 within tabhost inflated on View layout?

Tags: java, android

i'm in serious problem. I'm trying to get EditText from tab1 in Tabhost, but it keeps giving me error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference.
```

I have tried my code in many many different ways without any success! 
Here is my Code :

```
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View control_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_layout,null,false);
        TabHost tbhst = (TabHost)control_layout.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tbhst.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec tb1 = tbhst.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
        TabHost.TabSpec tb2 = tbhst.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
        TabHost.TabSpec tb3 = tbhst.newTabSpec("TAB 3");
        tb1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        tb2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        tb3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        tb1.setIndicator("CMD");tb2.setIndicator("Chat");tb3.setIndicator("Control");tbhst.addTab(tb3);tbhst.addTab(tb2);tbhst.addTab(tb1);
        LinearLayout gff = (LinearLayout)tbhst.findViewById(R.id.ggf);
        FrameLayout tbs_content = (FrameLayout)gff.findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        LinearLayout tbs1 = (LinearLayout)tbs_content.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        final EditText command_resualt_box = (EditText) tbs1.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
```

**UPDATE** :
as @popvitsj said maybe i'm making mistake but i tried to change it in layout/control.xml, but it gives me another different error and here is a Screenshot :[image: Screenshot]

and this the code in layout/control.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/control_q">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="410dp"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ggf">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/editText9"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="#ffff0c00"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText10"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="#ffff0c00"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                        android:linksClickable="true"
                        android:editable="false" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="260dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/editText11"
                            android:background="@android:color/black"
                            android:textColor="#ffff0c00"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/button11"
                            android:id="@+id/button12"
                            android:background="@android:color/black"
                            android:textColor="#ffff0c00"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="#ffff0c00"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText12"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="0.53"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE** : this code is giving an error you can take look on screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    FrameLayout tbs_content = (FrameLayout)gff.findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    LinearLayout tbs1 = (LinearLayout)tbs_content.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
```

The second of these lines gives the NullPointerException. So `tbs_content` is null, because it fails to load it on the first line.

It looks like you made a mistake specifying the id: `android.R.id.tabcontent` should most likely be `R.id.tabcontent`.

`android.R` is the R-class for the system resources. `R` is usually your own generated class (unless you import android.R).

Comment: when i write R.id.tabcontent it says doesn't exists!!

Comment: Check your `layout/control_layout.xml` if you're using the right id. If you are, try to clean your project. (Build -> Clean project in Android Studio)

Comment: Please add the xml source code instead of the screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you should change it back to `android.R.id.tabcontent` and change the id in your xml to `@android:id/tabcontent`

Comment: when i changed it gives me the first error mentioned above

Comment: thank you mate Now it's working! It was a mistake from me : instead of R.id.EditText11 it was suppose to be R.id.EditText12 and the same for the others mistake in numbering. THANK YOU ^^